# Pass double by reference C++

Tags: c++, pointers, double

Given

```
double skewAngle;
```

How could I pass this variable into a function and have it modified without returning the value?

My current function declaration looks like this:

```
Mat findCard(Mat& baseImage, double *angle)
```

When I try `findCard(baseImage, *skewAngle);`

I get a deceleration not found, can anyone show me how I can do this?

Comment: You're not passing by reference. You're passing a pointer.

Comment: @AliAlamiri; No need to pass by reference. Second argument should be passed by pointer as per the function prototype.

Comment: @haccks I know, I'm just informing the user as the title suggests he thinks he's passing by reference.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing the variable by pointer, not by reference, so you need to pass the address of the variable to the function, such as:

```
findCard(baseImage, &skewAngle);
```

If you want to pass it by reference, you need to change your function declaration to:

```
Mat findCard(Mat& baseImage, double& angle)
```

and then you can pass the variable directly to the function, such as:

```
findCard(baseImage, skewAngle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function call is wrong. You need to pass the address of the variable `skewAngle` as the second parameter of your function expects `double *`. Call it as

```
findCard(baseImage, &skewAngle);
```

Note that, as per your function declaration, only first parameter can be passed by reference. second parameter has to passed by pointer.